# Inserir dados na tabela com jsf,hibernate jpa

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa

Estou com problemas, no projeto que estou desenvolvendo em jsf usando jpa e hibernate.Não estou conseguindo cadastrar os dado do cliente no meu banco de dados como posso relaizar o cadastro ?

Codigo

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("WebApplication3PU");

EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
ClienteWeb cli= new ClienteWeb(); 
public ClienteWeb cadastrarCliente(){
           manager.getTransaction().begin();    
   manager.persist(cli);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();  
manager.close();

return cli;
    }
```

Cadastro do  cliente

```
public ClienteWeb cadastrarCliente(){

manager.getTransaction().begin();    
   manager.persist(cli);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();  
manager.close();

return cli;
    }
```

Metodo com os objetos retornados do form do jsf.

```
public Cliente montaCliente(){
    Cliente cli= new Cliente();
    cli.setNome(cli.getNome());
    cli.setEmail(cli.getEmail());
    cli.setSexo(cli.getSexo());
    cli.setEstado(cli.getEstado());
    cli.setSenha(cli.getSenha());
    cli.setData(cli.getData());
    cli.setCelular(cli.getCelular());
    cli.setCpf(cli.getCpf());
    cli.setCidade(cli.getCidade());
    cli.setCep(cli.getCep());
    cli.setConfirmar(cli.getConfirmar());
    cli.setRua(cli.getRua());
    cli.setNumero(cli.getNumero());
    cli.setBairro(cli.getBairro());
    cli.setUf(cli.getUf());
    cli.setLogin(cli.getLogin());

    return cli;
}
```

Minha duvida é como vou colocar os valores dos objetos digitados pelo usuario que eu pego com minha classe do magnedBean cliente  e colocar no metodo cadastrarCliente, sendo que nele eu persisto a base de dados da minha classe de entiade ClienteWeb ?

Minha classe de entidade

```
package Entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "ClienteWeb")
 @XmlRootElement

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "ClienteWeb")
  @XmlRootElement
  @NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM 
  ClienteWeb 
   c"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByCodigo", query = "SELECT c FROM 
   ClienteWeb c WHERE c.codigo = :codigo"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByEmail", query = "SELECT c FROM 
   ClienteWeb c WHERE c.email = :email"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByNome", query = "SELECT c FROM 
   ClienteWeb c WHERE c.nome = :nome"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findBySexo", query = "SELECT c FROM C 
   ClienteWeb c WHERE c.sexo = :sexo"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByEstado", query = "SELECT c FROM 
   ClienteWeb c WHERE c.estado = :estado"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findBySenha", query = "SELECT c FROM 
  ClienteWeb c WHERE c.senha = :senha"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByData", query = "SELECT c FROM 
   ClienteWeb c WHERE c.data = :data"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByCelular", query = "SELECT c FROM 
   ClienteWeb c WHERE c.celular = :celular"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByCpf", query = "SELECT c FROM 
   ClienteWeb 
   c WHERE c.cpf = :cpf"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByCidade", query = "SELECT c FROM 
   ClienteWeb c WHERE c.cidade = :cidade"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByCep", query = "SELECT c FROM 
  ClienteWeb 
 c WHERE c.cep = :cep"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByConfirmar", query = "SELECT c FROM 
  ClienteWeb c WHERE c.confirmar = :confirmar"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByRua", query = "SELECT c FROM 
ClienteWeb c WHERE c.rua = :rua"),
@NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByNumero", query = "SELECT c FROM 
 ClienteWeb c WHERE c.numero = :numero"),
@NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByBairro", query = "SELECT c FROM 
 ClienteWeb c WHERE c.bairro = :bairro"),
@NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByUf", query = "SELECT c FROM ClienteWeb 
c WHERE c.uf = :uf"),
@NamedQuery(name = "ClienteWeb.findByLogin", query = "SELECT c FROM 
 ClienteWeb c WHERE c.login = :login")})
public class ClienteWeb implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "codigo")
private Integer codigo;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "nome")
private String nome;
@Column(name = "sexo")
private String sexo;
@Column(name = "estado")
private String estado;
@Column(name = "senha")
private String senha;
@Column(name = "data")
private String data;
@Column(name = "celular")
private String celular;
@Column(name = "cpf")
private String cpf;
@Column(name = "cidade")
private String cidade;
@Column(name = "cep")
private String cep;
@Column(name = "confirmar")
private String confirmar;
@Column(name = "rua")
private String rua;
@Column(name = "numero")
private Integer numero;
@Column(name = "bairro")
private String bairro;
@Column(name = "uf")
private String uf;
@Column(name = "login")
private String login;
 @Column(name = "telefone")
private String telefone;

public ClienteWeb() {
}

public ClienteWeb(Integer codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public Integer getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getCelular() {
    return celular;
}

public void setCelular(String celular) {
    this.celular = celular;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

public String getCep() {
    return cep;
}

public void setCep(String cep) {
    this.cep = cep;
}

public String getConfirmar() {
    return confirmar;
}

public void setConfirmar(String confirmar) {
    this.confirmar = confirmar;
}

public String getRua() {
    return rua;
}

public void setRua(String rua) {
    this.rua = rua;
}

public Integer getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public String getBairro() {
    return bairro;
}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {
    this.bairro = bairro;
}

public String getUf() {
    return uf;
}

public void setUf(String uf) {
    this.uf = uf;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (codigo != null ? codigo.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof ClienteWeb)) {
        return false;
    }
    ClienteWeb other = (ClienteWeb) object;
    if ((this.codigo == null && other.codigo != null) || (this.codigo != null && !this.codigo.equals(other.codigo))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entity.ClienteWeb[ codigo=" + codigo + " ]";
}



}
```

Meu bean que faz contato com form jsf

```
@ManagedBean(name="cliente")
@SessionScoped
public class Cliente {


    private final  ClienteDAO dao= new ClienteDAO();

       public  String CadastroCliente(){

        dao.cadastrarCliente();

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("grow1");
        FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"","Cadastro Realizado com Sucesso"));
      return "Contato.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getCelular() {
        return celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(String celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getConfirmar() {
        return confirmar;
    }

    public void setConfirmar(String confirmar) {
        this.confirmar = confirmar;
    }

    public String getRua() {
        return rua;
    }

    public void setRua(String rua) {
        this.rua = rua;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

}
```

Comment: Desculpa, não consegui compreender muito bem, to tentando bolar uma resposta aqui. Me ajuda, sua classe `ClienteWeb` é a responsável por receber os dados do formulário preenchido pelo usuário? E você não esta conseguindo passar os dados da classe `ClienteWeb` para a classe `Cliente` que é salva no banco?

Comment: Brother, você está instanciando `Ciente cli = new Cliente()` e tá setando os valores de `cli`, que você acabou de instanciar em `cli`?

Comment: Seu objetivo não seria em montaCliente(), setar os valores que você pega do formulário de cadstro?

Comment: ex: `cli.setCampo(campo);`

Comment: manda o formulário também que fica melhor de ajudar

Comment: então henrique estou usando jsf , min ha duvida é como vou pegar os dados do jsf e persisti ele no banco de dados, sendo que no pesist tenho que colocar meu metodo de entidade entity ?

Comment: acrescentei as classe magnedBean e da entidade para vcs visualizarem melhor

Comment: Cara, o método `montaCliente()` não deve existir. Não faz o menor sentido. Na resposta que postei explico com os dados são transferidos do formulário para o managed bean. Você entendeu essa parte?

Answer (score 1):

Como você não postou o código da sua view, tomei a liberdade de criar alguns trechos de código:

---

**cadastraCliente.xhtml**

```
<form>
    <p:inputText value="#{clienteMB.cliente.nome}" />
    <p:inputText value="#{clienteMB.cliente.idade}" />
    <p:inputText value="#{clienteMB.cliente.endereco}" />
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{clienteMB.cadastraCliente}" />
</form>
```

---

**ClienteMB**

```
@ManagedBean
public class ClienteMB {

    private Cliente cliente;
    private ClienteDAO dao;

    public ClienteMB() {
        this.cliente = new Cliente();
        this.dao = new ClienteDAO();
    }

    public void cadastraCliente() {
        dao.cadastraCliente(this.cliente);
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return this.cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }
}
```

---

**ClienteDAO**

```
public class ClienteDAO() {

    EntityManagerFactory factory;
    EntityManager manager;

    public ClienteDAO() {
        this.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("WebApplication3PU");
        this.manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void cadastraCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();    
        manager.persist(cli);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();  
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

---

### Explicação

Para que você consiga transmitir os dados da página para o banco, é preciso primeiro passar os dados da *view* (xhtml) para o *controller* (ManagedBean).

Isso é feito pelo o atributo `cliente` da classe `ClienteMB`.

O JSF consegue popular esse atributo com os valores preenchidos quando informamos no `inputText` a propriedade `value="#{clienteMB.cliente.nome}"`, por exemplo. Dessa forma o valor digitado nesse campo será "setado" na propriedade `nome` do `cliente` de `ClienteMB`.

Depois disso é preciso preparar a classe `ClienteDAO` para que ela receba um `Cliente` para persistir (salvar no banco).

Isso é feito através do método `public void cadastraCliente(Cliente cliente)`. Perceba que esse método recebe um parâmetro chamado `cliente` do tipo `Cliente`.

No `ClienteMB`o atributo `cliente` é populado pelos valores dos inputs. Lá chamamos o método o método de cadastrado passando, justamente, o atributo `cliente` como parâmetro, ficando assim: `cadastraCliente(cliente)`.

Por fim, o cadastro é realizado quando o usuário clica no botão `<p:commandButton>`, que chama o método `cadastraCliente()` de `ClienteMB`.

Dessa forma é possível persistir no banco os dados oriundos da página.

---

### Pontos de Atenção

1. É imprescindível que o atributo `cliente` de `ClienteMB` tenha seus métodos  `getter` e `setter`. É através desses métodos que o JSF comunica a *view* com o *controller*
2. Existem diversas formas de se passar valores da *view* para o *controller*. Esse foi **um** exemplo
3. O DAO está sem nenhuma tratativa de exceção. Considere fortemente, usar `try catch finally` ou `try-with-resources`, caso esteja usando o Java 7 ou superior.

Comment: obrigado por responder Igor, então eu tenho que criar os gets e sets do Cliente assim exemplo clienteMB.cliente.nome

Comment: Os get e set são da forma que escrevi. Isso o que você escreveu é como a view insere os dados no ManagedBean

Comment: então os get e set estaram na classe cliente ?

Comment: Sim. Isso mesmo

Comment: man eu vou fazer desenvolver as correções e já te mostro o codigo se eu fiz esta certo e se a aplicação rodou, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: então Igor eu respondi minha pergunta para poder anexar a imagem e vc ver como ficou minha pagina xhtml, os componentes primefaces sumirão após eu colocar na view os magnedBean