# JSF - Passagem de parametro

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Tenho um formulário em JSF e estou precisando inserir os dados dele no banco de dados Já pesquisei de várias formas, mas não está funcionado

Poderiam me dar uma ajuda no que estou fazendo de errado?
JSF

**Formulário**

Não estou conseguindo passar o parâmetro do que esta sendo digitado para a inserção no banco de dados:

```
@ManagedBean(name="UsuarioJDCBDAO")

public void inserir(Usuario usuario) {

try {

Connection conexao = getConexao();

String value = null; Statement stmt = null; conexao.createStatement().execute("SET IDENTITY_INSERT "+"tbplan"+" ON"); stmt = conexao.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select MAX(id) + 1 from tbplan");

while (rs.next()) value = rs.getString(1).toString();

System.out.println(value);

PreparedStatement pstm = conexao .prepareStatement("Insert into tbplan (data, nome, frase, id) values (?,?,?,?)");

//String name = new Usuario().getNome(); //pstm.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(usuario.getDataCadastro().getTime())); pstm.setString(1, "26 Jun 2017 14:28:00:00");

pstm.setString(2, usuario.getNome());

// pstm.setString(2, n1.getNome()); pstm.setString(3, usuario.getFrase()); pstm.setString(4, value);

pstm.execute(); conexao.createStatement().execute("SET IDENTITY_INSERT "+"tbplan"+" OFF"); pstm.close(); conexao.close(); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}
```

**Classe usuário**

```
import java.io.Serializable; import java.util.Date;

public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -309513637403441998L;

private Long id;

private Date dataCadastro;

private String nome;

private String frase;

public Long getId() { return id; }

public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

public Date getDataCadastro() { return dataCadastro; }

public void setDataCadastro(Date dataCadastro) { this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro; }

public String getNome() { return nome; }

public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

public String getFrase() { return frase; }

public void setFrase(String frase) { this.frase = frase; }

@Override public String toString() { return "Usuario [nome=" + nome + ", frase=" + frase + ", dataCadastro=" + dataCadastro + " id=" + id + "]"; }
}
```

Comment: Você consegue receber esse parametro no seu ManagedBean?

Comment: coloquei um println e não consegui lista-lo

Comment: aparentemente o problema está justamente nesta passagem do jsf para o bean

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta clicando no botão editar logo abaixo das tags, dai você adiciona o código da pagina onde voce está tentando passar os valores

Comment: [Essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215854/5963) resposta vai te ajudar. Se não entender, chegando em casa posto uma resposta aqui

Answer (score -1):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/paginas/default/main.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1 class="page-header ">
            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> Formulário
        </h1>
                <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-2">

        <h:form>
            <b><h:outputText value="Nome: " /></b>
            <h:inputText class="form-control" id="nome" value="" />
            <br style="clear: left;" />
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <b><h:outputText value="Data: " /></b>
            <h:inputText class="form-control" value="#{now}">  
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo"/>  
            </h:inputText>
            <br style="clear: left;" />

        </h:form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <h:form>
            <td valign="top">
            <b><h:outputText title="Ajuda" value="Frase: " /></b>
            </td>
            <h:inputTextarea class="form-control"  cols="80" rows="8" id="frase" value="" />
        </h:form>
            </div>
            </div>
        <br style="clear: left;" />
        <div class="container">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2">

<h:form>
                        <h:commandButton id="submitBtn"  var="item" value="Incluir" class="btn btn-success" action="#{UsuarioJDCBDAO.inserir(Usuario)}">
                            <f:param name="Nome" value="#{item.nome}" />
                            <f:param name="Data" value="#{item.dataCadastro}" />
                            <f:param name="Frase" value="#{item.frase}" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:form>
</div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Formulário

```
    <h:form>
        <b><h:outputText value="Nome: " /></b>
        <h:inputText class="form-control" id="nome" value="" />
        <br style="clear: left;" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form>
        <b><h:outputText value="Data: " /></b>
        <h:inputText class="form-control" value="#{now}">  
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo"/>  
        </h:inputText>
        <br style="clear: left;" />

    </h:form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <h:form>
        <td valign="top">
        <b><h:outputText title="Ajuda" value="Frase: " /></b>
        </td>
        <h:inputTextarea class="form-control"  cols="80" rows="8" id="frase" value="" />
    </h:form>
        </div>
        </div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
    <div class="container">
```

```
</ui:define>
```

Comment: <h:form>
                        <h:commandButton id="submitBtn"  var="item" value="Incluir" class="btn btn-success" action="#{UsuarioJDCBDAO.inserir(Usuario)}">
                            <f:param name="Nome" value="#{item.nome}" />
                            <f:param name="Data" value="#{item.dataCadastro}" />
                            <f:param name="Frase" value="#{item.frase}" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:form>
</div>
 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para colocar informações adicionais

Comment: Edite a pergunta ao invés de responder